# why I got the error "Couldn't find article with id=ni-hao-wo-zhen-de-henhaoma" when using stringex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slug

I want to use [stringex](https://github.com/rsl/stringex) for more friendly url. Now my steps as follows:

(1) In the model called article:

```
  acts_as_url :title, :url_attribute => :slug

  def to_param
   slug
  end
```

(2) articles#show:

```
def show
  debugger
  show! do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
     format.json { render json: @article }
  end
end
```

(3) the articles/_article.html.erb includes:

```
<%= link_to(article_url(article)) do %>
... 
<% end %>
```

and correctly generates html tag, such as:`http://localhost:8000/articles/ni-hao-wo-zhen-de-henhaoma`

When I click the link generated in `(2)`, I got the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ArticlesController#show
Couldn't find Article with id=ni-hao-wo-zhen-de-henhaoma
```

I set a breakpoint in the entry of `ArticlesController#show`, but the above error come out before it.

What else steps should I do?

**Updated**: according to @jvnill's reminding, I think the backtrace maybe help:

```
activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:344:in `find_one'
activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:315:in `find_with_ids'
activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:107:in `find'
activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/querying.rb:5:in `find'
inherited_resources (1.4.1) lib/inherited_resources/base_helpers.rb:51:in `resource'
cancancan (1.10.1) lib/cancan/inherited_resource.rb:12:in `load_resource_instance'
cancancan (1.10.1) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:32:in `load_resource'
cancancan (1.10.1) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:25:in `load_and_authorize_resource'
cancancan (1.10.1) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:10:in `block in add_before_filter'
```

Comment: you should post your show action.  what most probably happens is that the fetching of the article happens in a before filter and it's finding by id instead of `Article.find_by!(slug: params[:id])`.

Comment: @jvnill, Thank you! I add the show action to the original question!

Comment: so like I said, `@article` has already been defined.  go to the `before_action` method that sets that and include the code for that.

Comment: When I add  `before_action :get_question_by_slug`, I got another error: `undefined method `before_action' for ArticlesController:Class. This is relative to an social network engine [social_stream](https://github.com/ging/social_stream)?
`

Comment: ah rails 4 is when `before_action` was introduced. change that to `before_filter`

Comment: I added `before_filter :get_article_by_slug, :only => :show` and `get_article_by_slug` include `@question = Question.find_by!(slug: params[:id])`, finally got the same error:  `Couldn't find Article with id=ni-hao-wo-zhen-de-henhaoma
?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go through the guide first so you can understand the flow better.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/action_controller_overview.html#filters

To answer your error, what happens is that `@article` is being set in a `before_filter` and it most probably finds the record by id

```
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
```

Since `params[:id]` is the article slug, what you want to do is find by slug instead.  So skip that before_filter for the show action and create another before_filter specifically for show action.  Something like the following.

```
before_filter :fetch_article, except: :show
before_filter :fetch_article_by_slug, only: :show

private

def fetch_article
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def fetch_article_by_slug
  @article = Article.find_by_slug!(params[:id])
end
```

**UPDATE**

Using the [inherited_resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) gem, you may want to implement your own show action (the following code is untested and I can't vouch for it since I've never used the gem before)

```
actions :all, except: [:show]

def show
  @article = Article.find_by_slug!(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: thank you! I used your new method and nothing changed. you means the key is to find  why @article is set before `ArticlesController#show`?

Comment: not why, where.  Where is @article being set?  That's where your error is and can easily be found by looking at the stacktrace.

Comment: I added some trace into my original question, please help me check it, thanks!  It seems that this error is relative to `inherited_resources` gem?

Comment: i'm sorry, just had a quick look at them gem because i've never used it before.  try my updated answer.