# How to enable two kinds of URLs http://ip:port/questions/:id and http://ip:port/questions/:id/:slug simultaneously?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inherited-resources

I used [stringex](https://github.com/rsl/stringex) to implement a more friendly url, like in stackoverflow, now I enable my url as follows:

```
http://localhost:8000/questions/12/i-want-to-display-the-url-like-stackoverflow
```

Of course, I found SO steps further, when entering

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30683457`

in url address bar, SO will redirect to the corresponding question

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30683457/why-i-got-the-error-couldnt-find-article-with-id-ni-hao-wo-zhen-de-henhaoma-w`,

but in my app, I used `find_by_slug!()` to get a record, so, when entering `http://localhost:8000/questions/12` it will throw a error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in QuestionsController#show

Couldn't find Question with slug = 12
```

How should I do to enable such two kinds of urls at the same time? Whether I can add a route rule for it, if yes, how to do it?

**NOTED**

Especially, because my Rails app is based on [social-stream engine](https://github.com/ging/social_stream), which includes a plugin [inherited-resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources), and `inherited-resources` has a default method `find_by_id()`, so I override it using `find_by_slug()`

**UPDATED**

After reading some manual about [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection), I enabled `http://ip:port/questions/:id`, such as, when I enter `http://localhost:8000/questions/12` it will redirect to `http://localhost:8000/questions/12/i-want-to-display-the-url-like-stackoverflow`, my resolution as follows with appending one rule in `routes.rb`

```
 match 'questions/:id' => redirect { |params, req|
   id = params[:id]
   slug = Question.find_by_id(params[:id].to_i).slug
   '/questions/' + id + '/' + slug
 }
```

I don't know whether this is a correct method?

Comment: If you are passing the `id` every time, why do you need to find by slug? In your `routes.rb`, you can add `get 'questions/:id/:slug' => 'questions#show'`

Comment: @abm you seemly don't understand my question! please read it again, thank you!

Comment: Why are you using `find_by_slug` if there is a possibility that `params[:slug]` is not always present?

Comment: @abm,  1. The error seemly is not relative to `find_by_slug` and `params[:slug]` because the error comes before `questions#show`.

Comment: looks like you've got it right.  since you ALWAYS have a `params[:id]`, there's no need to find by slug anymore.

Comment: @jvnill, Thank you! can you explain more about `since you ALWAYS have a params[:id], there's no need to find by slug anymore.`,  I have no idea how to avoid using `find_by_*` one more time here.

Comment: I am assuming this is connected to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30683457/why-i-got-the-error-couldnt-find-article-with-id-ni-hao-wo-zhen-de-henhaoma-w/30684032#30684032.  If it is, then you can remove the code that finds the article by slug since you always have the id available.

Comment: @jvnill, you means I can delete the override method 'find_by_slug' for 'find_by_id'? and I must modify the above content in `routes.rb`?

Comment: @jvnill Or you mean that I can use `redirect` for `http://localhost:8000/questions/:id/:slug` in routs.rb ?

Comment: if what you have there in your routes work, then what else do you need to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79937/discussion-between-abelard2008-and-jvnill).